# Understanding the HTTP POST request / response process

Tags: http, http-post

I've been trying to thoroughly understand the HTTP POST request / response process and although there are a lot of resources on google, none plainly give me the answer I'm after.

Example scenario:

I have a search form, I enter some query and make the request. I then get redirected to the search result page.

Could someone explain this process; in particular, I'm most interested in the redirection.

This is what I think is going on:

```
POST request containing query
        |
        v
Server receives request. 
        |
        V
Server sends back response containing the page that the client should subsequently request.
        |
        V
Client receives response and requests page indicated in the response.
        |
        V
Server receives request and sends back requested page.
        |
        V
Client renders page.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's exactly what happens. See [Post/Redirect/Get on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) for an explanation of this pattern.

The client performs the POST request:

```
Client -> Server: POST / HTTP/1.1 (+payload)
Server -> Client: HTTP/1.1 302 See other (+location header +payload)
```

Now the client sees the 302 and performs an additional request to the resource identified by the `location` header:

```
Client -> Server: GET $location HTTP/1.1
Server -> Client: HTTP/1.1 200 OK (+payload)
```

You can use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) for inspecting HTTP traffic.